# 404 error in servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

It's my first day trying servlets. It's just a simple login function, but I get an error that doesn't explain what I'm doing wrong. It just says

> 404: The requested resource is not available.

Here's my servlet:

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Login() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String key = "ole";
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        response.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp");
        if (session.getAttribute(username).equals(key)
                && session.getAttribute(password).equals(key)) {
            response.sendRedirect("secret.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp");
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

And here's my login page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>

    Enter username and password below.
    <form method=get action="hej">
        <input type="text" user="username" /> <input type="password"
            user="password" /> <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a file called `secret.jsp` as well, but there's nothing interesting in there. I don't understand why it's returning 404. When I have remove the if statement it works... only then, there's not much function.

Comment: What is the address displayed in the address bar when you get that 404?

Comment: A wrong name! So I learned that. It still gives me a NullPointerException at my if statement. I can't see what I'm not providing...

Comment: The stack trace tells you that. Read it. And post it if you don't understand it. Note that `<input>` doesn't have any `user` attribute. It has a `name` attribute though.

Comment: Make sure all your filenames are correct, and what the heck is `hej`

Comment: You are missing either `@WebServlet` or `web.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

As you say it works without `IF-ELSE` then I guess your `web.xml` entry is correct.

First change this to

`<input type="password" user="password" />`

this

`<input type="password" name="password" />`

`input tag` does not have any `user` attribute , it's `name`.

Next mistake is , you are using `session.getAttribute` to access  parameters that you have not set, yet.

Your code should be

```
if (username.equals(key)
        && password.equals(key)) {
    response.sendRedirect("secret.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp");
}
```

`session.getAttribute` can only be used when you have in your code `session.setAttribute` 
example `session.setAttribute("username","ole");session.setAttribute("password","ole");`.

Then only you could get a value with `session.getAttribute("username")` OR `session.getAttribute("password")`. But right now it only returns NULL. So code won`t work.

You could add this code in your existing code and it will work.

```
session.setAttribute(username,username);
session.setAttribute(password,password);
```

Your complete code should be

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
session.setAttribute(username,username);
session.setAttribute(password,password);

//response.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp");

if (session.getAttribute(username).equals(key)
        && session.getAttribute(password).equals(key)) {
    response.sendRedirect("secret.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I tried it out, I learned a lot from the post, however I still get a NullPointerException at the if. I also dont understand why it's not .setAttribute("username", username); ... you take the parameter from the .jsp file, yes?

Comment: @Rasmus why it's not .setAttribute("username", username); because you are accessing the attributes as session.getAttribute(username) not session.getAttribute("username"). For getting NULL at IF , either the value returned by getAttribute is NULL OR the attribute is not present. Can you provide your updated code

Comment: @Rasmus You can use session.getAttribute("username") if you set the attributes like this session.setAttribute("username", username);. Key should be matching.

Comment: @Rasmus you should also check if username or password are not NULL , before setting them as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace user="... by name="... in your HTML and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace user="... by name="... in your HTML and it will work. NullPointerException is thrown because because of the wrong HTML the request parameters are NULL and these are used for the session lookup.